# Can't contact LDAP server remotely from Mac

Tags: linux, mac-osx, ldap, arch-linux, slapd

I'm trying to configure a LDAP server with some basic security parameters, including TLS and required authenticated binding.

I have started the server, and can access it from localhost with the command:

```
ldapsearch -x -b 'dc=server,dc=com' 'objectclass=*' -W -D 'cn=manager,dc=server,dc=com' -H ldaps://server.com:389
```

When I try the same command remotely, from my computer, I get the following error message:

> ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

I don't know why this happens, I can ping my server and there is currently no firewall.

`slapd` is launched with `-h ldaps://server.com:389/`

DNS server is configured in a basic way on the same server, with only a A record.

Do you have any idea ?

EDIT

I've tested from another workstation, on arch-linux, and it works!
On both computer I have `TLS_REQCERT allow` in `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`, so that shouldn't be a certificate problem no?

The workstation on which the ldap query doesn't work is on Mac OS X, if that have any importance.

Some output:

Telnet:

```
telnet server.com 389

Trying w.x.y.z...
Connected to server.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Iptables:

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Netstat:

```
sudo netstat -lnt | grep 389

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:389             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::389                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

I've tested without any security parameters, and I have the same result.

Comment: tcpdumps, netstats, and firewall specifications would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using the standard port.  Start with `-h ldap:///`.  LDAP supports startTLS and can be easily configured to require TLS before passing sensitive information.

Telnet can be used to determine if you can reach the server.   Try the command `telnet server.com ldap`.  This should connect if the server address is correct.

On the server you can check to ensure that LDAP is bound to the external address using the command `netstat -lnt | grep 389`.  This will show which address you are listening on.

Once you have LDAP working without TLS enable startTLS and/or add `ldaps:///` to your startup.

You can use the option `security update_ssf=16 simple_bind=16` to require TLS for these operations.  Clients can then connect to the `LDAP` port and swistch to `TLS` using the startTLS operation.

EDIT:  Using debug on the client and/or server can be helpful in determining where the connection is failing.   Add `-d -1` to the command line to debug everything.   The debug switch accepts a bitmap of debug flags for various subsystems.  `-d ?` will list them and their values.  Once you know a subsystem is working, you can stop debugging and focus on other subsystems.

Starting debugging with the client is easiest, but it may be necessary to do some debugging on the server.  If you are logging via syslog, it is helpful to have a debug log file where you can examine the debug output.

Comment: Also, make sure your that your LDAP server has a certificate trusted by your LDAP client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the server configuration seems correct, as I can connect from another client.

Comment: The problem is that `-d ?` or `-d -1` is not taken in account by ldapsearch on my mac. Whatever I try I always get ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

Answer (score 2):

When you use an LDAP [URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4516) in the form
`ldaps://server.com:389`, the server will expect that
[SSL](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/32/sec/cat.elgamal.slides.html) negotiation will take
place when a client connects on port
`389`. [StartTLS](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/32/sec/cat.elgamal.slides.html) cannot be used
on an existing SSL connection: StartTLS 'converts' (perhaps *promotes* is a better word) an
insecure connection to a secure connection, therefore, since `ldaps://server.com:389` is already
a secure connection, StartTLS cannot be used. Your server should accept connections from
clear-text clients on `ldap://server.com:389` and reject any client connections that do not
immediately promote using StartTLS - if your server product cannot immediately reject unsecure
client connections, you should choose product that cat. If an SSL endpoint is also required, the
server should listen for secure client connections on `ldap://server.com:636`.